# Connect Facebook account and reward user for actions

Tags: facebook

We are in the process of implementing a user awards in mobile app.
I have news feed with URLs to Facebook posts and I want users to gain points for sharing and commenting this posts on their FB acounts.
Any idea how to implement this concept: a user share our post on facebook and app automatically rewards them points? Thanks

Comment: rewarding users for sharing and commenting is not allowed, as it generates spam

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-developer-policy-3.2